# Dll with MFC and static linking

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

I have dll using MFC and I need it to work on another computer without additional instalations.

If "C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library" is Multi-threaded DLL (/MD) and "General -> Use of MFC" is set to Use MFC in a Shared DLL - my dll needs msvcr80.dll.

If "General -> Use of MFC" is set to Use MFC in a Static Library and "C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library" to Multi-threaded (/MT) - I have an error 
`#error Please use the /MD switch for _AFXDLL builds`

Is there any solution? I'd appreciate any help. I'm searching the answer for a long time and in many places it is said that the second variant should work without errors.

Answer (score 1):

You should **build your client in the same mode as library** your link with.
Librarian warns you about that. So to resolve the error - build your client that uses MFC lib with **/MD flag** instead of /MT

Comment: And msvcr80.dll is to be additionally installed on another computer anyway, am I right?

Comment: Depends on type of linkage: if it is static - when no need in dll, else (dynamic) - such dll should be provided with you application.

Comment: And in my case static is impossible?

Comment: select the option to use the MFC as a statically linked library.

Comment: I wrote about it in my question: "If "General -> Use of MFC" is set to Use MFC in a Static Library and "C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library" to Multi-threaded (/MT) - I have an error #error Please use the /MD switch for _AFXDLL builds"

Answer (score 0):

MFC extension DLLs must be linked with the DLL version of MFC. Only MFC apps can be statically linked to the MFC framwwork.